# Blue selection border on input button on mobile (PhoneGap)

Tags: html, css

So, i'm using phonegap and i'm building an app's login screen, however, when I click on the login button it appears a blue selection border. I've tried:

```
button:focus {outline:0;}
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

style:

```
.button {
display: inline-block;
padding: 15px 25px;
font-size: 15px;
cursor: pointer;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
outline: 0;
height: 70%;
color: #fff;
background-color: #089FF5;
border: none;
border-radius: 15px;
box-shadow: 0 5px #0570ad;
outline-width:0px;
}

.button:active {
 background-color: #0570ad;
 box-shadow: 0 5px #0570ad;
transform: translateY(4px);
}
```

html:

```
<tr>
<td>            <input class="button" id="button" type="submit"    name="login" value="LOGIN"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you call this in a normal browser, so that you can access dev tools to inspect the element? It might be a different property, such as a box-shadow or similar ...

Comment: I don't know about phonegap but maybe try `button:focus {outline:0!important;}` to override the stylesheet with your own...

Comment: Didn't work. I've tried removing most box effects but it isn't working. Even if I remove the animation. On a regular button that doesn't happen

Answer (score 0):

I think handling both 'focus' and 'active' states of the button will solve the issue.

```
button:focus, button:active {
    outline:none;
}
```